# Making simple jQuery function more efficient

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a function and I know this is not the most efficient way to write it, not only for this function, but for others in the future.

It's the same lines except a number gets += 1 each time its repeated, so I'm sure theres a for, or if, or each way to loop this and reduce the code and increase the maintainability at the same time.

```
 function lines() {                     
     $('#bottom-1').lazylinepainter( 
     {
        "svgData": pathObj1,    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 



      $('#bottom-2').lazylinepainter( 
     {
        "svgData": pathObj2,    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 




     $('#bottom-3').lazylinepainter( 
     {
        "svgData": pathObj3,    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 



     $('#bottom-4').lazylinepainter( 
     {
        "svgData": pathObj4,    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 

     $('#solutions h2').delay( ).animate({opacity:'1'}, 1000, 'easeInQuint')
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div[id^="bottom-"]').lazylinepainter( 
     {
        "svgData": $(this).data('path'),    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter('paint');
```

And your div (or your dom element) like this:

```
<div id="bottom-1" data-path="path1"></div>
<div id="bottom-2" data-path="path2"></div>
<div id="bottom-3" data-path="path3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, not optimal but less text:

```
var svg1 = 0,
    svg2 = 1,
    svg3 = 2;

function test(idTag, svgDataTag, num) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        alert('#' + idTag + i); // element id 
        alert(eval(svgDataTag + i)); // svgData object
    }
}

test('button', 'svg', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  This solution doesn't require that you add any data to your div, or variables for each element that you have.  This will loop through every element that starts with "bottom-", pull out the number at the end, and add it to "pathObj".  This way, you really don't have to change a lot of code.  The only unknown that I have based on your code, is whether or not "pathObj" can be concatenated with the number.  If not, then there are ways around this as well that I can help you through.

```
$("[id^='bottom-']").each(function () {
    var idArray = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
    var idNumber = idArray[idArray.length - 1];
    $(this).lazylinepainter({
        "svgData": pathObj + idNumber,    //only line that changes
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeColor": "#fff"
    }).lazylinepainter("paint");
})
```

Since I don't really have any details on what "lazylinepainter" does, I tested my code like this to show an alert with the number that's being pulled from the ID:

```
<body>
    <div id="bottom-1" />
    <div id="bottom-2" />
    <div id="bottom-3" />
    <script>
        $("[id^='bottom-']").each(function () {
            var idArray = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
            var idNumber = idArray[idArray.length - 1];
            alert(idNumber);
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

And here's a fiddle that logs the numbers to the console so you can verify:

http://jsfiddle.net/9XZ2L/

If there's any other help you need, please let me know.